# Jquery Mobile interface on a site hosted on Google Drive

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I've uploaded my site to Google Drive for hosting, but when I go to it the page doesn't look the way it does locally. Its like none of the JQuery Mobile interface is working with it.

Does anyone know why this is happening/a way to remedy it? Thanks.

I've included my header for reference if need be

```
    <title>Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="128_icon.png"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="DoDjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link href="DoDCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No errrors at all. Just loads a page with no jquery mobile css added to it

Comment: It only acts this way when it's hosted on drive, locally it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google drive hosting does not allow loading content outside HTTPS, it gives errors like:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://foo/bar' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can fix that using `https` protocol in your CDN links.

Comment: As in change the source from "http:...." to "https:..."? I just did this but the page still doesn't look the way it does locally

Comment: Haha thanks, didn't even think that could be the issue there. This was the correct solution